# Как добавить элемент в многомерный JSON массив если ключ элемента переменная

Tags: javascript, json

Есть файл JSON с массивом вида

```
{
    "general_array":[
        {"key_1":["a","b","c"]}
    ]
}
```

Хочу добавить еще один элемент например

```
{"key_2":["d","e","f"]}
```

но при этом значение ключа `"key_2"` получаю с переменной например

```
var newKey = 'key_2';
```

Пытаюсь добавить в существующий массив следующим образом

```
// ... беру содержимое файла
// var jsonFileContent = '{"general_array":[{"key_1":["a","b","c"]}]}';

var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonFileContent);

var newKey = 'key_2';

jsonObj.general_array.push({newKey:['d','e','f']});

var newJsonFileContent = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);

// и перезаписываю обратно в файл ...
// console.log(newJsonFileContent);
```

Но в файле при этом получаю

```
{
    "general_array":[
        {"key_1":["a","b","c"]},
        {"newKey":["d","e","f"]}
    ]
}
```

т.е. в качестве ключа записывается НАЗВАНИЕ переменной, а нужно ее ЗНАЧЕНИЕ

Как занести значение переменной?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказывается все просто. Достаточно вставить `newKey` в квадратные скобки т.е.

```
jsonObj.general_array.push({[newKey]:['d','e','f']});
```

---

Хотя данный способ не работает в IE, в т.ч. IE11. Если нужна поддержка и для него, тогда более универсальный тот вариант, который предложил @Kosta B.

Правда вместо

```
var obj = new Object()
```

можно написать

```
var obj = {};
```

Comment: Способ, к-ый вы использовали, называется [_computed property names_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) и является частью ES6.

Answer (score 2):

> Как занести значение переменной?

Вот такой вариант:

```js
// ... беру содержимое файла
var jsonFileContent = '{"general_array":[{"key_1":["a","b","c"]}]}';

var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonFileContent);

var newKey = 'key_2';
// Создание объекта
var obj = new Object()
// Ключ 
obj[newKey] = ['d', 'e', 'f']

jsonObj.general_array.push(obj);

var newJsonFileContent = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);

console.log(newJsonFileContent);
```

Answer (score 2):

У меня была такая же проблема в IE11. Мое решение было таким.

```
let obj = {};
obj[newKey] =  ["d","e","f"];
jsonObj.general_array.push(obj);
```

Прекрасно работает в IE11 и Edge. Может быть, для кого-то это будет полезно.

Answer (score 0):

Можно переписать вашу строчку с добавлением нового ключа следующим образом:

```
jsonObj.general_array.push(`{${newKey}:['d','e','f']}`);
```

тогда newKey будет восприниматься как переменная и в JSON вы будете получать ее значение.

Comment: Но тогда во-первых ключ записывается в файл без двойных кавычек, а во-вторых в его массиве т.е. `'d','e','f'` кавычки однинарные, а нужно двойные